# DPF lighting up problem

Tags: honda

I have a Honda CrV Diesel 2.2L. The DPF light turned on and i lost power. The car has chip. I have twice my car regenerate then I get back the power of my car. Then after 1 week the DPF turn back on. The third time i took the chip out still did not work. Honda told me that the DPF is not full.
What will be exactly the problem.

Thank you 
Best regards

Comment: I appreciate that this is a frustrating problem for you but please don't post duplicates of your question - it's only going to make it confusing and harder for you to get the answers you need.

Comment: What year is the car? I've heard of some issues similar to this on ~2012 model CRVs where Honda claimed it was a software issue that could be resolved with an update - although there's been mixed reports about the efficacy of the "fix"